# Using ros2_control with both position and velocity controller

Tags: ros2-control, ros2-controllers

I have eight motors, 4 for steering and 4 for driving mobile robot. I would like to control steering motor with position controller and driving motor with velocity controller...is this possible? I tried using `JointGroupPositionController` and `JointGroupVelocityController` and when I send `[0, 0, 0, 0]` to position controller, steering motors go to 0 position, but then I try to send `[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]` to velocity controller and driving motors start driving a bit and then return to 0...does anyone know why is that..am I missing something?

I am using ROS2 Humble, and latest ros2_control.

My yaml file is below:

```
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 100  # Hz

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

    velocity_controller:
      type: velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController

    position_controller:
      type: position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController

velocity_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - FL_wheel
      - BL_wheel
      - BR_wheel
      - FR_wheel

position_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - FL_steering
      - BL_steering
      - BR_steering
      - FR_steering
```